# Dynamic mapping in Salesforce - generate JSON request for call third-party API

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I want to generate JSON string from Account sObject field which also contains other sObject.
Please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, the best way to go about this without using middleware is to create a custom metadata type for the API mapping. It will store the JSON key, SObject name, and SObject field.

You can use that data to generate a dynamic SOQL query and then create a map (Map) that can be serialized.

The complexity depends on the JSON you need to generate. If you need sub-objects or arrays of objects in the JSON, it can get complicated.